# How to change folder name to ubuntu root directory

Tags: php, ubuntu, command-line, mv

I am trying to change folder name on Ubuntu root directory. It is working from terminal, but when I apply the same command in PHP, the name is not changed.

```
exec("mv old_name new_name");
```

I have also tried this:

```
exec("mv /old_name /new_name");
```

Comment: In which SAPI (CLI, Apache, PHP-FPM, etc.) are you running the PHP script? The user of the process may have no sufficient privileges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **rename** — Renames a file or directory

```
<?php
rename("/tmp/tmp_file.txt", "/home/user/login/docs/my_file.txt");
?>
```

For more info refer this link: http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php

Comment: I am getting permission denied error using this because i wan to change folder in root directory  /folder_name

Comment: its working when i hit the page using command line but when i run page using browser it didn't worked

Comment: i think You're editing the higher level directory, so the PHP user needs to have write access to that directory.

Comment: Thats probably because apache is not the owner of the parent directory.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132749/discussion-between-nitin-patel-and-bilal).